# What volume should i delete if i want to uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, partitioning

I want to delete my ubuntu from this computer and i'm having a problem by not knowing what partitions I  need to delete.

here is a screenshot :

[image]

if you can recognize which number i need to delete i will be thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

First, *don't delete Ubuntu's partition without first adjusting the boot order!* Many people make this mistake, and it results in the computer booting to a `grub>` prompt, which is confusing and unhelpful.

The easiest way to adjust the boot order on an EFI-based computer (which yours seems to be) is to use the third-party Windows [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) program. Click the entry for the Windows boot manager in the list and move it to the top of the list using the up-arrow button. If you don't do this, many computers provide a built-in boot manager you can use, but details vary from one machine to another. Typically, you access the boot manager by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually F8 or above). You'll then see a list of boot entries, one of which should take you to Windows, where you can use EasyUEFI to adjust the boot order.

With that done, you can identify and delete your Ubuntu partition. Unfortunately, the Windows partitioning tools don't know a thing about Linux filesystems, so they don't show sufficient detail to be 100% positive. It looks like the partition you've identified as #4 is your Linux swap space and #5 is your root (`/`) partition, but I can't be certain of that. It's best to boot into Ubuntu and check this detail before you begin. You can use GParted to identify your partitions or examine the `/etc/fstab` file to see what's mounted where. (Note that `/etc/fstab` will likely have an entry for your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition), but you *must not* delete that partition. Likewise, there might be entries for Windows partitions.)